# Command Line GPIO Access - Pin Types (Orange Pi)

Tags: gpio

I am trying to set GPIO pins to high and low state on an Orange Pi using the following command:

```
echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio_sw/PA1/data
echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio_sw/PA1/data
```

This turns the pin on and off.

The `/sys/class/gpio_sw/` folder has locations labeled

```
PA0, PA1, PA10, PA13, PA14, PA2, PA21, PA3, PA6, PA7, PA8, PA9
PC4, PC7
PD14
PG6, PG7, PG8, PG9
```

Do the prefixes `(PA, PC, PD, PG)` have any meaning?

Are these all references to GPIO pins?

Comment: My first thought is it is similar to how Arduino has PORTB, PORTC, and PORTD like in this image: https://www.peterbeard.co/postimages/digitalwrite/atmega168-pins.png

Comment: @solve that's really how every microcontroller and other ics are,  not just arduino

Answer (score 4):

The Allwinner SoCs divide their I/O pins into banks, somewhat like many smaller MCUs do.   In some Linux versions these designations are passed through in some cases, in others or at least other contexts they are simply re-numbered, probably starting with 0 for `PA0`, adding 32 for `PB0`, etc in order to yield a more usual `/sys/class/gpio/gpio0` etc

Ultimately you'll have to consult the references (or source) of your particular operating system flavor, its device tree (if utilized, or legacy configuration if not) your board documentation, and possibly the relevant SoC datasheet.

One resource you probably want to consult is http://linux-sunxi.org/GPIO